# why the input process cannot go back after else in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have 2 inputs for my app, `a` and `b`. I want to show the inputs if my initial variable is not 0. Here is my code:

```py
import random
init = 100
while init > 0:
    x = random.randint(0,24)
    a = int(input("input value a:"))
    if a < 25:
        b = int(input("input value b"))
        if b <= init:
            init -= b
        else:
            print("b should smaller than init")
    else:
        print("a should between 0 and 24")
```

When I run and put a value for `a` more than 25, I got the `else a < 25`, and redirect again to input value `a` again until it is less than 25. When I put value `b` more than `init`, the output from `else b <= init` was printed but I was not redirected to input `b` again, instead to input value `a` after `while`. How do I redirect to the part where I input `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `b` will not be redirected again if it is greater than `init` is that it's value is removed from `init`, so `init > 0` becomes false.

I would recommend trying this:

```
import random
init = 100
a = 25
b = 101
while init > 0:
  x = random.randint(0,24)
  a = int(input("input value a:"))
  if a < 25:
    b = init + 1
    while b > init:
        int(input("input value b"))
        if b > init:
           print("b should smaller than init") 
  else:
    print("a should between 0 and 24")
```

Basically what this does is it sets `b` to be greater than `init` so the `while b > init` loop activates, and it keeps prompting the user with `print("b should smaller than init")` until they enter a value of `b` less than `init`.

**Update**

Here is the code to get out of the while loop, as OP asked in the comments:

```
import random
init = 100
while (a > 24 or a < 0) and b < init:
  x = random.randint(0,24)
  a = int(input("input value a:"))
  if a < 25 and a > 0:
    b = init + 1
    while b > init:
        int(input("input value b"))
        if b > init:
           print("b should smaller than init") 
  else:
    print("a should between 0 and 24")
```

Comment: yaps, this answer redirect to the part that I input `b` but how can I stop the `while` when `init` is 0 because substracted by `b`?

Comment: @Rian Ah, of course, sorry. I don't see how `init` would be stopped by subtracting `b` in this situation as `b` is less than `init`, so subtracting `b` would keep `while init > 0` as true. Do you want to exit the while loop when `a` is between 0 and 24 and `b` is less than `init`? If so, reply and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thats true, when `a` is between 0 and 24 and `b` less than `ini`. Thanks

Comment: @Rian Ok, I've updated the answer and it should have the code you need. If there are any problems please comment.

Comment: if I use this `while (a > 24 or a < 0) and b < init:` first, `a` and `b` is not defined yet

Comment: I got it, with your first answer, I add it `and init != 0` in `while b > init` and it works. thanks

Comment: @Rian Ah of course sorry. What you need to do is define `a` and `b` before the `while`, I've updated my answer to be correct.

Comment: @Rian oh okay, cool. If there is anything else that isn't working please ask.